# Problem with using cv2.pointPolygonTest() and cv2.polylines()

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw a shape and then check whether the point is inside the shape or no. Thought using `cv2.polylines()` to draw it and `cv2.pointPolygonTest()` to test should work am getting an error which is not very informative.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Heatmap\cvtest.py", line 32, in <module>
    dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0, 255 , 0), 2), (52,288), False)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\geometry.cpp:103: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32S || depth == CV_32F) in function 'cv::pointPolygonTest'
```

I am guessing the shape created with `cv2.polylines()` is not a contour. What would be the correct way to do it then? My current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')

pts = np.array([[18,306],[50,268],[79,294],[165,328],[253,294],[281,268],[313,306],[281,334],[270,341],[251,351],[230,360],[200,368],[165,371],[130,368],[100,360],[79,351],[50,334],[35,323]], np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))

dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0, 255 , 0), 2), (52,288), False)
#print(dist)

cv2.imshow('test', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`polylines` is not the right input, it is used to draw a shape ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaa3c25f9fb764b6bef791bf034f6e26f5))
`pointPolygonTest` instead needs the contour as an input ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722))

`dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(pts, (52,288), False)` will return `1.0`, meaning inside the contour.

Note that you can perform a pointPolygonTest without an image. But if you want to draw the results, you can use this code as a starter:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    #create background
    img = np.zeros((400,400),dtype=np.uint8)
    # define shape
    pts = np.array([[18,306],[50,268],[79,294],[165,328],[253,294],[281,268],[313,306],[281,334],[270,341],[251,351],[230,360],[200,368],[165,371],[130,368],[100,360],[79,351],[50,334],[35,323]], np.int32)
    pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
    # draw shape
    cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(255), 2)
    # draw point of interest
    cv2.circle(img,(52,288),1,(127),3)
    # perform pointPolygonTest
    dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(pts, (52,288), False)
    print(dist)
    # show image
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]